# CakePHP User Role Retrieval

Tags: php, cakephp

Im trying to pass a condition to my UserController in order to view certain Users whose Role matches to the page I'm trying to access.

For example:

/admin   => User.admin

/student => User.student

I'm able to retrieve a list of all registered students using the find('all') function, but when I try to filter roles through setting conditions I'm getting an error that references my code and the role I'm trying to retrieve.

Here's my function in my controller:

```
    public function index($role="admin") {
        //debug($role);
        $this->User->recursive = 0;
        $this->request->data('users', $this->User->find('all', 
            array('conditions' => 'User.role')));
        $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
    }
```

Any tips?

Comment: try this  public function index($role="admin") {
        //debug($role);
        $this->User->recursive = 0;
        $this->request->data('users', $this->User->find('all', 
            array('conditions' => array('User.role'=>'admin'))));
        $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
    }

Answer (score 0):

`conditions` should be an array of conditions.

i.e. `array('role' => 'role_value')`

See documentation at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Answer (score 0):

For adding conditions, use **`WHERE`** option with **`find()`**.

Like:

```
public function index($role="admin") {
    $this->User->recursive = 0;
    $this->request->data('users',
        $this->User->find()->where(['conditions' => 'User.role']));
    $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
}
```

OR

If `role` is the *DB table field name*, the code is simple:

```
public function index($role="admin") {
    $this->User->recursive = 0;
    $this->request->data('users',
        $this->User->findByRole());
    $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
}
```